# How to dynamically add input fields to a form 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working with Asset Management system. The company is spread through out different locations.

This system can return asset items to store again if these items are not in use.

What I want to do is return the item there are lots of items. So I have input fields like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="asset_id[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="batch_code[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description[]"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="status[]"/></td>
// current condition of the item
```

I can't use these fields again and again, I don't know how many fields are required for each particular situation.

If I can give an option to the user to add input fields if he/she needs, how do I do this.

Comment: i tried add fields again and again. finally i felt it was not practical. I searched it in google also. but cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can see something like that
http://jsfiddle.net/damian_silvera/ATzne/

Answer (score 0):

Using JS/jQuery propably :

HTML :

```
   <a href="#" id="plus_row">Add Row</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a#plus_row").click(function(){
     $("table#form_table").append($("table#form_table").find('tr').get(0));
   });
});
```